# Multi-site execution : Getting rid of virtual table with inheritance (legacy code)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, inheritance, virtual

I've been stuck for some time on this problem, and I need your help.

My C++ application is running on multiple exec sites. My problem is that I cannot pass objects holding a virtual table, because sites do not share memory (thus a virtual method from a given object will lead to an undefined behaviour). By "I cannot pass" I mean : I do not want any virtual table.

The fun thing is there's not only inheritance, but also templates and eerie conception...

Here is the code

```
// "Main" code
List< Animals, 5 > list;
List< Animals, 8 > list2;
list.concatenate( list2 );

// GenericList.hpp
template< Type >
class GenericList 
{
 virtual getBuffer(void) = 0;
 virtual getSize(void) = 0;
 void concatenate( GenericList<Type> gList)
 {
  int size = gList.getSize(); // Call to the child...
  ...getBuffer()...
  // processing, etc.
 }
}

// List.hpp
template< Type, Size_ >
class List : public GenericList< Type >
{
 int getSize()
  {
   return Size_;
  }
 Type * getBuffer()
  {
   return buffer;
  }
 Type buffer[Size_];
}
```

**How can I get rid of inheritance ?**

EDIT/ In light of the first few answers, I can tell you that I **cannot** implement a better serialization, the code being private.

Comment: What exactly are you serializing? If you create the object on the other side and fill it's members with the same value, the virtual table should be valid on the new site as well.

Comment: What about getting rid of virtual functions using CRTP?

Comment: @RedX : It's not exactly serialization but rather multi-frequency (one site for each frequency). So basically, the object is the same on one side or another.
sharptooth : I'll look into that, thanks. Why didn't post as an answer ? ;)

Comment: How is the data serialized? Does your serialization scheme just do a cast to `char*` and then sends it over the wire with `sizeof` as the byte count? Knowing more about how the data is sent allows us to give you better suggestions.

Comment: That's exactly how it's done; Anonymous buffers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of virtual tables, you don't have to get rid of inheritance. You have to get rid of virtual functions. Looking at the code you post, maybe you can make a few changes so that `getSize` and `getBuffer` are in `GenericList`, so you can make them non-virtual, but that really depends on the rest of your code.

The first question is, however, why would you worry about virtual tables in the first place? When you serialize the objects, you should serialize their data in order to preserve their state, and the state is the only thing you should pass around.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I cannot move any of the two because "Size_" is only defined in the child. As said in the comments, it's not exactly serialization but multifrequency. it's a shame but I cannot change the way objects are passed between frequencies (it's a java/C middleware).

Comment: @Isaac, what exactly is that frequency thing?... Are objects passed around by reference? Can you access data allocated on the heap, but not the vtables? As for making functions non-virtual - maybe you can have a `size` member variable, that will be set on the constructor or so, and it's value will be returned instead of `Size_`. This way you can keep a non-virtual `getSize()` in `GenericList`, and still return the value of `Size_` when using `List`.

Comment: No, the objects are passed as anonymous buffers. I'm gonna try your method, thanks ;)

Comment: @Isaac, if you end up stuck with the vtable, another (somewhat ugly) option is to restore the right vtable pointer after the deserialization. Objects of the same type point to the same vtable, so if you create a dummy instance of `List` on the target, you can assign its vtable pointer to any `List` object you get from the wire. Assuming the memory layout of the objects is the same on both ends (no different alignments), it should "revive" your received objects.

Comment: I finally managed to solve my problem : I duplicated the attributes in the mother class, and initialized them in the child constructor... Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I think you are blaming the wrong part of the problem there... if you have a distributed system, you have to make sure that the serialized data that is sent on the wire contains enough information to rebuild the state of the object on the other end of the connection.

I believe that the problem you are facing is that you are sending raw data over the wire, while you should have a serialization mechanism that is able to encode the actual type of the object being sent and rebuild the object on the opposite end with the exact same type. In the case of an object belonging to a class with virtual functions, that will mean that the two objects are not equal *bitwise*, as on each end of the connection the pointer to the vtable will refer to a different location in memory, but they will be *semantically* equal, which is what you need to be able to process the objects on the other end.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I agree with you, but (there's always a but) I cannot modify the serialization mechanism... So I just have to find a workaround